# JQuery disable or alert choises based on form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is about reservation system

Suppose each room has capacity of 10.

Number of people already in the room will be displayed in the table data `<td>` 'class'

```
<td class='5'>1</td>
<td class='7'>2</td>
<td class='9'>3</td>
<td class='3'>4</td>
<td class='2'>5</td>
<td class='7'>6</td>
```

Numbers in 'class' represents number of people in that room. 1,2,3 to 6 are room numbers

I have text input field with `<input name='people' type="text">` to get value of number of people I am reserving for.

The requirement now is, if I have entered '4' in the people input, I can not click on and reserve room No 2 as it has 7 people already and capacity is 10. I should be able to click on other room which has 6 people or less mentioned in `<td class=>`

Comment: I am not clear on what the issue is.  Can you expand on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to know `what room they are trying to reserve`, `how many people they are trying to reserve`, `how many people are already reserved`, and `what the max capacity` is when the user clicks "reserve."

If I were you, I wouldn't be using class to store the data. I'd use the `data` attribute. I'd do the following:

```
<td id="15" data-currentFilled="7" data-maxcapacity="10">table 15</td>
```

1. Store the table id using the `Id` attr
2. Store the current # of people reserved for that table in the
   `currentFilled` attr
3. Store the max capacity in the `maxcapacity` attr

Then your javascript would need to be something like this:

```
$(".reservationSave").click(function() {

  // Get the table trying to be reserved and how many they're trying to reserve
  var tableBeingReserved = $(this).attr("id");
  var howMany = parseInt($(".reservingGuestsNumber").val());

  // Find out how many people are currently reserved and max capacity
  var currentFilled = parseInt($("td#15").attr("data-currentFilled"));
  var maxCapacity = parseInt($("td#15").attr("data-maxcapacity"));

  if (currentFilled + howMany > maxCapacity) {
    alert("Cannot save. Too many people");
  }

});
```

Now, of course you will have to tweak some names, etc but here's a jsbin to help you out:

**http://jsbin.com/hopuqujoli/edit?html,js,output**

Comment: Your answer has max capacity built in the individual place to be reserved. That will add more power to the reservation system where some places can have different capacity. Example you provided also runs as explained by you. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use data attributes to store and retrive such element data. it can be set as:

```
<td data-number="5">1</td>
```

and can be retrived using:

```
$('your-td-element').data('number')
```

and then you can check if the input is less than or equal to empty slots or spaces in a room.

Answer (score 1):

First, typically it's best not to keep data about a certain element in the class attribute (since that's predominately used for styling), that's usually something you'd do in a normal attribute or a data attribute e.g:

```
<td class="myClass" data-count="7">15<td>
```

What you can do is if you give all the rooms a name like so:

```
<td name="Room15" data-count="7">15<td>
<td name="Room16" data-count="8">16<td>
<td name="Room17" data-count="3">17<td>
```

You can use the jquery selector of: `$('td[name^="Room"]')` and that will give you all td elements who's name STARTS WITH "Room". From there loop through them and do whatever you want with them. You could disable the element if it fails your check, or add possible candidates to some list and then output the list. As you're looping through in the .each function, you can grab the value in the data-count attribute of the current element using either:

```
this.attr("data-count")
```

or since it's specifically a data attribute

```
this.data("count")
```

Comment: Your answer also deserves more than just +1 but the one I accepted as answer has additional power of max-capacity with working example.